# Laravel: How to display in table 4 different named columns who belongsTo 1 model

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have 4 columns: activist_id_1, activist_id_2, activist_id_3 and activist_id_4 in add_members table. They all **belongsTo** Activist model:

AddMember model:

```
public function activist()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Activist', 'activist_id_1', 'activist_id_2', 'activist_id_3', 'activist_id_4');
    }
```

If I try to display table like this:

```
<td>{{$add_member->activist_id_1 ? $add_member->activist_id_1->name : ''}}</td>
<td>{{$add_member->activist_id_2 ? $add_member->activist_id_2->name : ''}}</td>
<td>{{$add_member->activist_id_3 ? $add_member->activist_id_3->name : ''}}</td>
<td>{{$add_member->activist_id_4 ? $add_member->activist_id_4->name : ''}}</td>
```

shows me Trying to get property of non-object...

if I try:

```
<td>{{$add_member->activist_id_1 ? $add_member->activist->name : ''}}</td>
<td>{{$add_member->activist_id_2 ? $add_member->activist->name : ''}}</td>
<td>{{$add_member->activist_id_3 ? $add_member->activist->name : ''}}</td>
<td>{{$add_member->activist_id_4 ? $add_member->activist->name : ''}}</td>
```

shows me SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'activists.activist_id_2' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `activists` where `activists`.`activist_id_2` = 1 and `activists`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1)

I don't know how to use activist method that I made i AddMember model. Maybe the foreign keys are wrongly added?

I try in different way, I make members method in Activist model:

```
public function members()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\AddMember', 'activist_id_1', 'activist_id_2', 'activist_id_3', 'activist_id_4');
    }
```

where method is **hasMany** but always getting error.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create one function per activist id. Ex:

```
public function activist1()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Activist', 'activist_id_1');
}

public function activist2()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Activist', 'activist_id_2');
}
```

And then call them like this:

```
<td>{{$add_member->activist1->name or ''}}</td>
<td>{{$add_member->activist2->name or ''}}</td>
```

Additionally, in Blade you can use `or` inside brackets to avoid null relations.

Comment: I do not know why I thought that it can do everything in one method and it does not have to be more :) Yes, this is working, thanks @Laerte ;)

Answer (score 0):

Each activist is a related with a function,
and you have `AddMember` model:

```
public function activist1()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Activist', 'activist_id_1');
}

public function activist2()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Activist', 'activist_id_2');
}
public function activist3()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Activist', 'activist_id_3');
}

public function activist4()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Activist', 'activist_id_4');
}
```

Display table:

```
<td>{{$add_member->activist1->name or ''}}</td>
<td>{{$add_member->activist2->name or ''}}</td>
<td>{{$add_member->activist3->name or ''}}</td>
<td>{{$add_member->activist4->name or ''}}</td>
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many